# Keeping user information for non-consumable in-app purchasees on local device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

I have an Pro Upgrade-like feature on my app, where I am going to enable extra features to user. I would like to keep this information on the local device when bought (non-consumable in app)

I would like to reach this info when user deleted and re-installed the app or when the app is updated. I am not planning on reaching this info after OS Updates, Restores etc.

I am not trusting on NSUserDefaults, seems like when the user deleted the app, NSUserDefaults are lost.

My app requires a server, so a server authentication for this state can be done, but I cannot figure out how.

Waiting for advices for both local and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be confident in using `NSUserDefaults` freely, a backup is created when doing a device backup with iTunes.

Then, to restore purchases, just forget about storing them somewhere and use the appropriate method:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

This will automatically call

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

of the SKPaymentTransactionObserver associated with the payment queue. You can either restore purchases every time the application is launched or provide the user a button to force it.

In addition it will call the appropriate delegate methods as if purchases has been made so you don't have to manage separate ways of enabling purchases.

Comment: During development, when the app is deleted from device, NSUserDefults is gone. Is this only for development stage?

Comment: No, it will be deleted but restored easily if a backup was made through iTunes. In any case, according to Apple guidelines, you are supposed to use the restore payment mechanics without worrying to provide a way to store purchases after uninstall.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean... since I have used only consumable in-apps (and they were controlled at the server) so far, I haven't implemented the payment restore mechanism. Thanks for pointing it out! Any good tutorials you can point me at, other then dev.apple?

Comment: Actually there is nothing to know, just the fact that when calling that method the same callbacks that are usually done for a real purchase will be done for every purchase already made. So you just need to decide when to call it :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! So I don't even have to hold on to the receipt. I could just stock the info on the NSUserDefaults, and when it is not reached, I can call the restoreCompletedTransactions and I am ready to go!